SemanticUI Toggle Baseline
I would like to align my toggle in the middle of the line together with other form elements like input boxes. Here is the HTML:


.ui.toggle.checkbox {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.ui.toggle.checkbox label {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
<div class="ui toggle checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="stromlos" id="stromlos">
  <label>Stromlos</label>
</div>



any ideas? It's doing nothing :-(


Try setting the width of the div to 100% and switch vertical-align with justify-content like so:


 .elements{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ui.toggle.checkbox >label  {
  margin-left: 0.5em; 
}
<div class="elements">
  <div class="ui toggle checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="stromlos" id="stromlos">       
        <label for="stromlos">Stromlos</label>
  </div>
</div>




it doesn't work. Perhaps Semantic UI overwrites it everytime?

@SimonGiesen if .ui.toggle.checkbox is already referenced by Semantic UI you can create a wrapper and handle the layout that way (Code editted).
